# Need to populate from one table to another table - Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.

Table A has 1 column. Date(Say 22/1/2020)

Table B - Has 2 columns. Id and Value

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | 0,0,5,1,2,1,3 |
| B896 | 5,0,0,0,10,58 |

These values actually represents values for different dates. Need to join table B with table A to get the start date.
Here the value 0,0,5,1,2,1,3 means 0 for 22/1/2020, 0 for 23/1/2020, 5 for 24/1/2020 and so on.

Table C - Has 2 columns. Id and Date. This is the output table.

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |

I need to insert the id and dates for which the values are 0 in table B into table C.

Expected output in table C is this:

| Id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A123 | 22/1/2020, 23/1/2020 |
| B896 | 23/1/2020, 24/1/2020, 25/1/2020 |

Comment: Edit your question and show the data in a *text table* format.  The question is not clear.

Comment: Search for mysql split string.

Answer (score 0):

With `INSERT INTO` you take results from tablea into tableb. It would be more useful for us to provide some sample data.

```
INSERT INTO tableB(ID)
SELECT ID
FROM tableA
WHERE VALUE = 0
```