# Adding comma seperated column values in a table

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, addition

I have 2 columns in a table.

```
|  values_1 | values 2 |

| 1,2,3,4   | 5,6,7,8  |
```

I need to add both column values..i.e, the result should be 6,8,10,12

Comment: You do this by **fixing your data model**.  Numbers should not be stored as strings.  Arithmetic should not be performed on string values.  String columns should not contain multiple values.  Fix your data model!

Comment: Do you really store comma separated values, or is it just poorly presentation?

Comment: You've been struggling with this data model for a while by the looks of it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845676/need-to-populate-from-one-table-to-another-table-sql

Comment: Comma separated items is nothing but asking for SQL problems...

Comment: Deepa Das -  If one of the answers for this question resolved your issue, you can help the community by marking that as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously should not use such a data model, because it will bring a lot of trouble with it. But if you have no other choice then you need to find at least some solution.

With MSSQL, you can perform the following query to get the result you desire:

```
SELECT a.id, a.values_1, a.values_2, v1.rowindex_left, v2.rowindex_right, v1.value as lefty, v2.value as righty, CAST(v1.value AS INT)+CAST(v2.value AS INT) as result 
    FROM testtable a
        CROSS APPLY (select value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value ASC) AS rowindex_left from string_split(values_1, ',')) as v1
        CROSS APPLY (select value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value ASC) AS rowindex_right from string_split(values_2, ',')) as v2
        where v1.rowindex_left = v2.rowindex_right
```

BASE:

[image]

RESULTS:
[image]

What it does:

- it transforms your data (by using string_split), so that you can use each value for further calculation
- SELECT-clause: the values of v1.value and v2.value are casted from varchar(x) to a INT and are added together
- WHERE-clause: only display the data, where the rownumber is matching (to represent the desired calculation)

You always need to prepare your data first, so that you then can use the seperate values for your calculation.

Now, we can perform the following Statement, to put the seperated values together:

```
SELECT id, STRING_AGG(result, ',') from (
    SELECT a.id, a.values_1, a.values_2, v1.rowindex_left, v2.rowindex_right, v1.value as lefty, v2.value as righty, CAST(v1.value AS INT)+CAST(v2.value AS INT) as result 
    FROM testtable a
        CROSS APPLY (select value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value ASC) AS rowindex_left from string_split(values_1, ',')) as v1
        CROSS APPLY (select value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value ASC) AS rowindex_right from string_split(values_2, ',')) as v2
        where v1.rowindex_left = v2.rowindex_right 
    ) t group by id
```

Afterwards, you should get the following result:

[image]

If you have a lot of data, you could insert the seperate values from v1+v2 into another table and then perform the needed calculations - this would boost the performance a lot, if you need to perform calculations on this dataset many times.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL you can split a string into a table (`regexp_split_to_table`). After that you can paste the tables into columns of your source table (`from rows from`). You have to keep the right order (`with ordinality`). Then you can add the two values after converting them to integers (`::int`). In order to convert the summed values back into an array, you have to group them by the original values (`group by`). Then you can aggregate the summed values into an array (`array_agg`) while keeping the original order (`order by ordinality`). Next you can format the array as string (`array_to_string`).

Example ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/deddc/1/0)):

```
-- table
create table "values"
(
  "values 1" text,
  "values 2" text
);

-- data
insert into "values" values ('1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8');
insert into "values" values ('11,22,33,44', '55,66,77,88');

-- select
select
  "values 1", "values 2",
  array_to_string(array_agg (s order by ordinality), ',') "values 1+2"
from
  (select
     "values 1", "values 2", ordinality,
     v1::int + v2::int s
   from
     "values",
     rows from
     (regexp_split_to_table ("values 1", ','),
      regexp_split_to_table ("values 2", ','))
     with ordinality alias (v1, v2)) tmp
group by "values 1", "values 2";
```

Don't expect this to be fast.